# My ISP is injecting .swf into my webpage. How legal is this?

Tags: internet, india, is-x-legal

I recently saw a pop-up, on a http page. It was the advertisement of some offers provided by the ISP.

Here is the code:

```
<td>
  <object width="480" height="195" data="<url>/V3/front_porch_RAN.swf" style="pointer-events:none;>...</object>
</td>
```

There is no javascript that is collecting my data, but is indulging in the activity of injecting code into the webpage, legal? I live in India.

Comment: Does your contract with your ISP say they can do that?

Comment: Unless there is a law or contract saying they can't, then it's legal.

Comment: @Mark please notice that even if the contract says they can, this does not mean it magically becomes legal "whatever" it says.

Comment: @feetwet no, it is not an answer, unless either you cite a specific law, OR you are knowledgable enough with Indian law to state that there isn't.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. Firstly there wasn't a contract. Secondly, I think usually the issue is privacy invasion and not code injection. Is it?

Comment: "Firstly there wasn't a contract" Not even a verbal one? If they agreed to a given downstream bandwidth, these injected packets are eating into that bandwidth.

Comment: What does this code mean? What consequences does it have?

Comment: @ohwilleke
 It displays some content in a box of a specified size that is part of a table structure. The content is whatever is at the specified URL, and could change at any time. The OP said what was displayed was an "advertisement of some offers provided by the ISP".

Answer (score 4):

Unless there is a law or regulation against it, it is legal.

However in a big government it can be practically impossible to determine whether something is legal.  For example, [nobody even knows how many *criminal statutes* have been promulgated by the U.S. federal government](http://blogs.loc.gov/law/2013/03/frequent-reference-question-how-many-federal-laws-are-there/).  And that's nothing compared to the volume of executive regulation and judicial case-law that determines whether something is illegal.

I.e., in practice determining that something is *legal* is a bit like proving a negative.

Furthermore, if you look long enough [some argue](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424052748704471504574438900830760842) that you can probably find some law under which almost any action could be considered illegal.

Note also that even if it is not against the law, it could be proscribed by contract (read your Terms and Conditions!), and breach of contract is *in general* – but with an astonishing number of exceptions! – illegal.

Comment: "Unless there is a law or regulation against it, it is legal." Not so, there are many common law precedents that make things illegal for which no statute or administrative law exists.

Comment: @DaleM - I assume you mean "case law?"  Which I'll admit I glossed past, but which only further supports the substance of this answer.  I.e., "Oh, so you somehow managed to find and digest *every law passed by every legislative body, and every regulation promulgated by the executive of every government entity with jurisdiction*?  Great, now get started on the *case law* that could potentially be cited by any court that might claim jurisdiction."

Comment: @feetwet which is the **best** argument against common law and for Code Civil type law: precedent is a *mess*

Comment: The Feds publish all their laws in three volumes: a) the US Constitution, b) USC, and c) CFR.  That's it.  There's no mystery there.  The States also publish the same 3, then you have city ordinances.  That's it. That's all you have to search for criminal laws.  *Case law only interprets; it can't make something criminal that wasn't before.*